# How to set Custom Text into DropdownList in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have dropdown list control in one of my application and when I add Items in it from database Its displaying the first Item into Dropdown list by default but I want to display someother text into this like  "Select Item from the List"  Is there any way I can do this .

Also Can you please help me setting the same value from javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the ASP.NET side of things, you can create the DropDownList with AppendDataBoundItems="true" and any items you bind to it will come after the default:

```
<asp:DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems="true" ID="yourListId" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select something" Value="-1" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

As for doing the same thing completely in Javascript, you can do it with a function like this:

```
function addFirstItem(list, text, value)
{
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.text = text;
    newOption.value = value;
    list.options.add(newOption);
}

addFirstItem(document.getElementById("yourListId"), "Select something", "-1");
```

Or with jQuery (there is probably something much cleaner, especially for creating a new option tag, but this works):

```
$("#yourListId option:first").before("<option value='-1'>Select something</option>");
```

Comment: addFirstItem(document.getElementById("yourListId"), "Select something", "-1");
 
is giving error saying that object expected

Comment: If that is the line generating the error, you need to actually have a list with ID="yourListId" (or change the ID used in getElementById). I was simply putting "yourListId" in as a placeholder. If it is a line within addFirstItem that is having the error, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Patridge answer is correct, however if you are using the asp method and still run into a problem, add the items tag to the listitem.

```
<asp:DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems="true" ID="yourListId" runat="server">
  <items>   
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select something" Value="-1">--Select Something--</asp:ListItem>
  </items>
</asp:DropDownList>
```